# click on button1 and add text to div, click on button2 and remove text and css style button1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click on .add-btn, I change the .add-btn's style to background:#cccccc and change the val() to "-".

Now when I remove the added text with tr td .list that is a row in a list, I want that .add-btn button that added the deleted row to style back to background:#232323 with val() "+".

The problem I have is that there is 10 buttons with classname .add-btn, and how will I now which of the 10 buttons that has been clicked, to add text?

```js
jQuery("tr td .list").live('click', function() {
    jQuery(this).closest("tr td").remove();
});

                   
jQuery(".add-btn").click(function(event) {
    jQuery(this).val("-");
    jQuery(this).css("background", "#cccccc");
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tbody>
<tr></tr><tr><td><div class="list"><p class="delete-list-domains">X</p>added text in a list</div></td></tr><tr></tr>
</tbody>

<input type="button" value="+" class="btn-xs add-btn btn-circle" id="add-btn">
<input type="button" value="+" class="btn-xs add-btn btn-circle" id="add-btn">
<input type="button" value="+" class="btn-xs add-btn btn-circle" id="add-btn">
<input type="button" value="+" class="btn-xs add-btn btn-circle" id="add-btn">
<input type="button" value="+" class="btn-xs add-btn btn-circle" id="add-btn">
```

Comment: first of all live() function is depricated use $().on('click', function(){}); instead, now the $(this) return the current clicked btn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign different id for each button, giving same id is wrong.

```js
$("tbody").on('click', '.list', function() {
    console.log($(this).find("tr"));
    var btn = $(this).data('id');
    $('#'+btn).trigger('click');
    $(this).remove();
});


$(".btn-xs").on('click', function(event) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if($(this).hasClass('add-btn')) {
      $(this).removeClass('add-btn')
        .addClass('rm-btn')
        .val('-')
        .css('background','#cccccc');
      $('tbody').append('<tr><td><div class="list" data-id='+id+'><span class="delete-list-domains">X</span> added text in a list by '+id+'</div></td></tr>');
    } else if($(this).hasClass('rm-btn')) {
      $(this).removeClass('rm-btn')
        .addClass('add-btn')
        .val('+')
        .css('background','#fffff');
        $('[data-id="'+id+'"]').remove();
    } else {
      alert('error')
    }
});
```

```css
.delete-list-domains{ color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tbody id="content">

</tbody>
</table>
<hr/>
<input type="button" value="+" class="btn-xs add-btn btn-circle" id="add-btn1">
<input type="button" value="+" class="btn-xs add-btn btn-circle" id="add-btn2">
<input type="button" value="+" class="btn-xs add-btn btn-circle" id="add-btn3">
<input type="button" value="+" class="btn-xs add-btn btn-circle" id="add-btn4">
<input type="button" value="+" class="btn-xs add-btn btn-circle" id="add-btn5">
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, Its working after a little twist in the code :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can target only a clicked button whilst adding the event to all of them in vanilla JS:

```
const btnEls = document.querySelectorAll('.add-btn')

Array.from(btnEls).forEach(btnEl => {
  btnEl.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // do whatever you want to button here (use btnEl var)
  })
})
```